# Using linq to query a nullable field

Tags: c#, linq

This is my first post, I hope the phrasing of my question makes sense, let me know if not.

I am struggling to write a linq query where the field I'm evaluating is nullable.

I have a collection of objects which has a nullable enum field and an id field (filteredCollection). I also have a collection of enums in a list (SearchCriterionQualificationUnitLevels).

I want to get a subset of the objects collection where the enum field matches one of the values in the list.

At the moment I have the following code which is working but I'd be interested in finding out how to achieve the same result without having to jump through so many hoops.

```
Dictionary<int, QualificationLevel> unitsWithLevels = filteredCollection.Where(x => x.QualificationLevel != null).ToDictionary(k => k.QualificationUnitID, v => v.QualificationLevel.Value);

var matchingUnits = from unitWithLevel in unitsWithLevels
                    join unitLevels in SearchCriterionQualificationUnitLevels on unitWithLevel.Value equals unitLevels
                    select unitWithLevel.Key;

filteredCollection = from unit in filteredCollection
                     join matchingUnit in matchingUnits on unit.QualificationUnitID equals matchingUnit
                     select unit;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in singe statement (new lines added for readability)

```
Dictionary<int, QualificationLevel> unitsWithLevels = 
filteredCollection
.Where(x => x.QualificationLevel != null 
&& SearchCriterionQualificationUnitLevels.Any(unitLevel => unitLevel.Equals(x.QualificationLevel.Value)));
```

Comment: It's actually simpler as I only used the dictionary to get a collection of the units that have a QualificationLevel. So it becomes:  `filteredCollection = filteredCollection.Where(x => x.QualificationLevel != null && SearchCriterionQualificationUnitLevels.Any(unitLevel => unitLevel.Equals(x.QualificationLevel.Value)));`

Answer (score -1):

```
var subset=filteredCollection.Where(i=>SearchCriterionQualificationUnitLevels.Any(l=>l==i.QualificationLevel));
```